# Argument Being Set to Null

Tags: c#, wpf

The following is a fragment of the code from a class derived from `ComboBox`.

```
private string _selected;

public void SetSelected(string color)
{
    if (!IsLoaded)
    {   
        _selected = color;
        return;
    }

    foreach (ComboBoxItem each in Items)
    {
        if (each.Tag as string == color)
        {
            each.IsSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If execution reaches the `foreach` loop, `color`, no matter what argument I pass to `SetSelected`, is `null`.

This has me completely stumped. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I changed the code to the following, which works perfectly, and only increases my confusion as to why the first method does not work.

```
private string _selected;

public void SetSelected(string color)
{
    _selected = color;

    if (!IsLoaded)
        return;

    foreach (ComboBoxItem each in Items)
    {
        if (each.Tag as string == _selected)
        {
            each.IsSelected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're passing `null` to the method. Since there is nothing here that is changing `color`, the only conclusion is that it was `null` to begin with. Check the code that calls `SetSelected`. The code in your question is not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to do `each.Tab.ToString()` in the foreach loop? Because there is nothing that would set it to null.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I have verified with the VS debugger that the argument `color` is not null as soon as execution enters the function.

Comment: Yes, well, then you're not describing the right problem. Again, there is nothing here changing `color`. It cannot be `null` when you reach the `foreach` statement if it was not `null` when the method was called. **Why** do you think that it is null? How do you verify that it is null?

Comment: Are you sure that 'each' is not null?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Perhaps another section of code could be modifying a variable inside this function, although I do not see how that would be possible. And yes, it throws a `NullReferenceException` if I try to use the variable.

Comment: Well, color could be changed from another thread--capturing the value would be the correct course, then.

Comment: No, you cannot modify a variable or parameter "from the outside". A string is also immutable, and even if you managed to change the value of the string, you could still not change the parameter from being non-null to being null. **This is not the problem**

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson No, because if you changed `color` from another thread you would have to change whatever data the caller would hold on to, the string being passed to `SetSelected` would not change. First, a parameter (unless it is declared as `ref` or `out`) is passed by copy, and a string is immutable. Basically, this is not the problem. Again, I'm wondering how he came to the conclusion that `color` was non-null first, and then null afterwards. How is he verifying this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I am using the VS debugger. I am stepping through each line; when control enters the function, `color` has a value, e.g. "BLUE". As soon as control hits the `foreach` loop, `color` has a value of `null`.

Comment: Can you show screenshots? Because if what you say is true there is something deeply buggy in the compiler or debugger here.

Comment: Are you calling this method on multiple threads btw? And is this the **exact** code you're using, or have you simplified it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: It is not a debugger issue. The only reason I started to debug was because the program was not working as expected. I am not calling the method on multiple threads. As I showed in the post edit, the second method works fine.

Comment: Is the code as posted the exact code you're using?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes sir.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43789/discussion-between-ming-slogar-and-lasse-v-karlsen)

Comment: You're not trying to debug the release build are you?

Comment: @MarkFeldman: No, but as you can see in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43789/discussion-between-ming-slogar-and-lasse-v-karlsen the problem magically disappeared.